# Selenium C# How to get image and fill in web form

Tags: c#, image, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to write capcha from this (https://file-online.taxservice.am/pages/loginPage.jsf)  site and fill in textbox above.

```
            var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
            var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, new ChromeOptions());
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://file-online.taxservice.am/pages/loginPage.jsf");
            var ocr = new IronTesseract();

            IWebElement captchaImage = driver.FindElement(By.Id("mainForm:captchaImage"));

            using (var input = new OcrInput(capchaImage))
            {
                var result = ocr.Read(input);
                string result1 = Regex.Replace(result.Text, @"\s", "");
                string result2 = Regex.Replace(result1, @"\B\p{Lu}", m => m.ToString().ToLower());

                driver.FindElement(By.Id("userName")).SendKeys("1");
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("tin")).SendKeys("2");
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("3");
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("captchaEntry")).SendKeys(result2);
            }
```

Comment: Typically capchas require a special tool to solve. Especially if image processing is involved. [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1425/).

Comment: Do you know simple captcha solving tool for c#?

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic for this site. You should be able to search for it.